# How to rollback the changes made to /etc/security/limits.conf?

Tags: unix, ubuntu-16.04

I am setting up kafka-cluster on AWS. In order to change the number of files a process can open at a time I ran the following command.

```
echo "* hard nofile 100000 * soft nofile 100000" | sudo tee --append /etc/security/limits.conf
```

By mistake I ran it twice and the limits.conf file looks like below (last few lines)

```
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
# End of file
* hard nofile 100000
* soft nofile 100000
* hard nofile 100000
* soft nofile 100000
```

How do I revert it back?

Comment: What about `sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf` Then type `G3k` to go to the 4th last line, then `4dd` to delete them, then `:wq<ENTER>`.

Comment: Is this question literally just "how do I edit text files?" or am I missing something?

Comment: I tried doing that but the file does not have write permission. I think I can grant the write permission and  edit the file by deleting the last two lines, but afraid it might break something. Is it advisable?

Comment: The file is "append-only"? Then you need to remove that property first.

Comment: The file has permission like this -rw-r--r--(read ,write for me), but when  I open it in editor it gives warning like this : (Warning : No write permission) . Am I missing something here?